# JPA save failing and transaction rolling back

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to get a record from db and comparing with dto for auditing purpose. If i found a record, I am updating record with updated field and setting the primary key id to null and trying to save it as a new record. If there is no record in db, i am conveting the dto to entity and just saving it.

```
List<AuditReconciliation> auditiedList = reconDao.getAuditedReconActionDtlList(Arrays.asList(entity.getReconActionDtlId()));
    AuditReconciliation auditRecon = !auditiedList.isEmpty() ?auditiedList.get(0) : new AuditReconciliation();
    if(!entity.getDisposition().equals(auditRecon.getDisposition())) {
    auditRecon.setLastEditedDate(entity.getLastEditedDate()!= null? entity.getLastEditedDate():presentDate);
        auditRecon.setReconActionDtlAuditId(null);
        return auditRecon;
```

while saving i am getting org.hibernate.HibernateException: identifier of an instance was altered from 1 to null 2021-02-04 21:02:27.983 ERROR 14048 --- [io-8080-exec-24] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor : Application exception overridden by commit exception.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As far as I know, if you want to save a new record, you have to create a new instance of entity. Setting to null will not work as object is tied to persistence context when you fetch record.

Answer (score 0):

As per your explanation, setting null to the primary will not insert the new record, also it will not update null to the primary key so resulting in the error, as an `object is tied with persistence context`

What should be your solution
`Scenario 1:` If I found a record

> `Solution 1:` Try to update the same record with new fields without setting null to the primary key.
> `Solution 2:` Delete an existing record and insert the new one.

`Scenario 2:` If no record found

> `Solution`: Insert new record directly as you mentioned.